# QlikView Count with multiple Condition

Tags: qlikview

I have a problem with Count and multiple condition:

I have two fields, `Product_Type` and `color`
color has two Data {black,white}, I want to Count `Product_Type` in each Color and try this:

```
Count(Distinct(if(Color='black' or Color='White',Product_Type)))
```

but it doesn't work correctly,in each type it shows same number for each color.

Comment: in what object/chart you are trying this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Count only white color:

```
Count({<Color={'White'}>} Distinct Product_Type)
```

Count only black color:

```
Count({<Color={'Black'}>} Distinct Product_Type)
```

Count white AND black colors:

```
Count({<Color={'White','Black'}>} Distinct Product_Type)
```